# Do the dimensions of a volume of water affect the ripples generated from a standard object dropped? Is there a formula which represents this?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Assume there is a standard item dropped from a standard distance into a standard volume of water. Do the dimensions of the water affect the ripples generated and is there a formula which describes this?

Comment: You can do a rather nice version by using $x\mapsto\sin(\Vert x-c\Vert+\varphi)$ to get your basic "ripple" - then scale it WRT to $\Vert x-c\Vert$, note that $\Vert x-c\Vert$ is really just "radius from $c$" ($c$ being the centre of the ripple). Using dimensional analysis you can find a function $f:r\mapsto f(r)$ such that $:x\mapsto f(\Vert x-c\Vert)\sin(\Vert x-c\Vert+\varphi)$ is "valid" for the steady state of something moving up and down. Hint: $f:r\mapsto r^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ - after that there are very few expressions and we must use numerical simulation.

Comment: (Comment size limit, hence 2) For example there are very few closed form equations for the shape of waves on the surface of an "ocean". It's only known for homogeneous and infinite (deep, and in every surface direction) oceans, but that's an approximation (I know there's a 3rd order one which involves $\cos^3(\text{blah blah blah})$ - but again, approximation) - so to answer "no there isn't". Furthermore consider "standard object dropped" you'd need a perfect sphere in a continuous fluid to get radial symmetry. (Otherwise angle cube dropped would matter for instance)

Comment: "wave equation" and "PDEs" are good places to start if you want to read more. We understand waves fairly well (ignoring travelling waves on an ocean *smirk*) - but yeah that's kinda it.

Comment: .... serious question now; should I just copy and paste that into an answer? It's like 3 paragraphs. Or have I already committed?

Comment: .... serious question now; should I just copy and paste that into an answer? It's like 3 paragraphs. Or have I already committed?

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes, better to write this as an answer. Then you can delete the comments.